# Android Room - Cannot resolve method/symbol when defining Room tablename, ColumnInfo etc

Tags: android, database

I'm trying to set up a Room database in my app. Here is a Entity class:

```
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity(tablename = "items")
public class ItemEntity {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;
    @ColumnInfo(value = "value")
    public float value;
}
```

Android studio tells me it `cannot resolve method tablename` and `cannot resolve method value`. Same with my ItemDao class, where I define a query: `@Query("SELECT * FROM items")`. Here it tells me it `cannot resolve symbol items`. I've set up Room in my gradle file, and the android imports are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Entity` annotation parameters are case sensitive. Try using `tableName` instead of `tablename`.

Comment: You're right. It's `tableName` instead of `tablename`. And instead of `@ColumnInfo(value = "value")` it's `@ColumnInfo(name = "value")`, as it says in the docs, I don't know why I did it the way I did. Also fixing `tablename` fixed the `items` error too. So everything is working. What a rookie mistake. Thank you and I think I'll go to bed now...